# : Error: The argument type 'BuildContext Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, visual-studio, computer-science, developer-tools

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:mingle_flutter/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:mingle_flutter/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:mingle_flutter/widgets/follow_button.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;
  const ProfileScreen({Key? key, required this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  var userData = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    try {
      var snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(widget.uid)
          .get();
      userData = snap.data()!;
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(
        context,
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        title: Text(
          userData['username'],
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/04/15/06/32/river-7133713__340.jpg',
                      ),
                      radius: 40,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              buildStatColumn(20, "Posts"),
                              buildStatColumn(100, "Followers"),
                              buildStatColumn(5, "Following"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              FollowButton(
                                text: 'Edit Profile',
                                backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
                                textColor: primaryColor,
                                borderColor: Colors.grey,
                                function: () {},
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'username',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 1,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Some description',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Column buildStatColumn(int num, String label) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          num.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

: Error: The argument type 'BuildContext Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
lib/screens/profile_screen.dart:36

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1
  context,
  ^

: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.
lib/screens/profile_screen.dart:37

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1
  e.toString(),
  ^

This is the error I am getting
getData() async { try { var snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('users') .doc(widget.uid) .get(); userData = snap.data()!; setState(() {}); } catch (e) { showSnackBar( context, e.toString(), ); } }

Comment: I am getting error on showSnackBar(
        context,
        e.toString(),
      );

Comment: Could you show the code of `showSnackBar`

Comment: getData() async {
    try {
      var snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(widget.uid)
          .get();
      userData = snap.data()!;
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(
        context,
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }

Comment: What I mean is the code of function, how you define `showSnackBar`?

Answer (score 0):

you will be try this :

```
 catch (e) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
            content: Text('Save failed: ${e.toString()}')
        )
      );
    }
```

Comment: That didn't work. Still giving me error. lib/screens/profile_screen.dart:18:56: Error: Can't find '}' to match '{'. class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> { ^ lib/screens/profile_screen.dart:18:7: Error: The non-abstract class '_ProfileScreenState

Comment: Probably because of this ${e.toString()} . Can you try this : print(e.toString());
var snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString()));
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);